# CONTIKI -- COOJA WiFi Simulation with APs and Mobile Nodes

Tags: networking, wifi, simulation, contiki, cooja

I am working on a project which needs a network simulation in COOJA. The simulation  should have WiFi Access Points and mobile nodes. RSS based Indoor Navigation algorithm works as backbone.

As I am new to Cooja, I would like to get a suggestion on simulating the above said network. Is WiFi Radio Interference simulation possible with Cooja, if yes a guidance on methodology for this simulation is what am expecting. Please do guide and help me.

Thanks,

Manu

Comment: You can't simulate WiFi in Cooja. You can simulate some simple generic interference though.

Comment: I have WiFi library for Contiki , is there any way to interface WiFi library in COOJA ?